# When I set width in the middle div and zoom out to 25% it's not in one line

Tags: html, css

When I set width(310px) in the middle div(section-2) and zoom out to 25%, it's not in one line. Is it a problem? and solution to make it in one line.

Note: I am using google chrome and it's look fine in google chrome when zoom out to 100% but not in 25%. I have also provided images so you can answer quickly.

I need your help.

```css
.structure {
  max-width:1190px;
  padding-left:15px;
  padding-right:15px;
  margin:0 auto;
}

.contact-info-area {
  background:white;
  border-top:1px dashed #ccc;
  border-bottom:1px dashed #ccc;
}

.contact-info-area .contact-info {
  position:relative;
} 

.contact-info-area .contact-info .section-1 {
  float:left;
}

.contact-info-area .contact-info .section-1 .sec:first-child {
  width:70px;
  height:70px;
  background:white;
  float:left;
  border-radius:50%;
  -moz-border-radius:50%;
  -webkit-border-radius:50%;
}            

.contact-info-area .contact-info .section-1 .sec:last-child {
  margin-left:23px;
  float:left;
}

.contact-info-area .contact-info .section-1 .sec:first-child .fas.fa-mobile {
  font-size:30px;
  position:relative;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
  -moz-transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
  -webkit-transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
  -o-transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
}                    

.contact-info-area .contact-info .section-1 .sec:last-child .phone-number-title {
  font-family:avant_garde_cedemi;
  font-size:1.013em; /* 16.208px */
  margin-top:2px;
  letter-spacing:0.075em;
  text-transform:uppercase;
}

.contact-info-area .contact-info .section-1 .sec:last-child .number-1 {
  font-family:avant_garde_cebook;
  font-size:1.013em; /* 16.208px */
  margin-top:21px;
  letter-spacing:0.075em;
}

.contact-info-area .contact-info .section-1 .sec:last-child .number-2 {
  font-family:avant_garde_cebook;
  font-size:1.013em; /* 16.208px */
  line-height:150%;
  letter-spacing:0.075em;
}

.contact-info-area .contact-info .section-1::after {
  content::"";
  display:table;
  clear:both;
}

.contact-info-area .contact-info .section-2 {
  width:310px;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
}

.contact-info-area .contact-info .section-2 .sec:first-child {
  width:70px;
  height:70px;
  background:white;
  float:left;
  border-radius:50%;
  -moz-border-radius:50%;
  -webkit-border-radius:50%;
}            

.contact-info-area .contact-info .section-2 .sec:last-child {
  margin-left:23px;
  float:left;
}

.contact-info-area .contact-info .section-2 .sec:first-child .fas.fa-map-marker-alt {
  font-size:30px;
  position:relative;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
  -moz-transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
  -webkit-transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
  -o-transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
}                  

.contact-info-area .contact-info .section-2 .sec:last-child .address-title {
  font-family:avant_garde_cedemi;
  font-size:1.013em; /* 16.208px */
  margin-top:2px;
  letter-spacing:0.075em;
  text-transform:uppercase;
}

.contact-info-area .contact-info .section-2 .sec:last-child .address-1 {
  font-family:avant_garde_cebook;
  font-size:1.013em; /* 16.208px */
  margin-top:21px;
  letter-spacing:0.075em;
}

.contact-info-area .contact-info .section-2 .sec:last-child .address-2 {
  font-family:avant_garde_cebook;
  font-size:1.013em; /* 16.208px */
  line-height:150%;
  letter-spacing:0.075em;
}

.contact-info-area .contact-info .section-3 {
  float:right;
}

.contact-info-area .contact-info .section-3 .sec:first-child {
  width:70px;
  height:70px;
  background:white;
  float:left;
  border-radius:50%;
  -moz-border-radius:50%;
  -webkit-border-radius:50%;
}

.contact-info-area .contact-info .section-3 .sec:last-child {
  margin-left:23px;
  float:left;
}

.contact-info-area .contact-info .section-3 .sec:first-child .fas.fa-envelope {
  font-size:30px;
  position:relative;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
  -moz-transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
  -webkit-transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
  -o-transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.contact-info-area .contact-info .section-3 .sec:last-child .email-address-title {
  font-family:avant_garde_cedemi;
  font-size:1.013em; /* 16.208px */
  margin-top:2px;
  letter-spacing:0.075em;
  text-transform:uppercase;
}

.contact-info-area .contact-info .section-3 .sec:last-child .email-address-1 {
  font-family:avant_garde_cebook;
  font-size:1.013em; /* 16.208px */
  margin-top:21px;
  letter-spacing:0.075em;
}

.contact-info-area .contact-info .section-3 .sec:last-child .email-address-2 {
  font-family:avant_garde_cebook;
  font-size:1.013em; /* 16.208px */
  line-height:150%;
  letter-spacing:0.075em;
}

.contact-info-area .contact-info .section-3::after {
  content::"";
  display:table;
  clear:both;
}                    

.contact-info-area .contact-info::after {
  content:"";
  display:table;
  clear:both;
}
```

```html
<section class="contact-info-area" id="contact-info">

  <div class="structure">
 
   <div class="contact-info">
 
    <div class="section-1">
     
     <div class="sec">

      <i class="fas fa-mobile"></i>
     
     </div>
     
     <div class="sec">
     
      <h3 class="phone-number-title">PHONE NUMBER</h3>
      
      <p class="number-1">+1 234 456-789</p>
      
      <p class="number-2">+123-456-7890</p>
     
     </div>
     
    </div>
    
    <div class="section-3">
     
     <div class="sec">
     
      <i class="fas fa-envelope"></i>
     
     </div>
     
     <div class="sec">
     
      <h3 class="email-address-title">EMAIL ADDRESS</h3>
      
      <p class="email-address-1">johnsmith@company.com</p>
      
      <p class="email-address-2">youoffice@company.com</p>
     
     </div>
     
    </div>
   
    <div class="section-2">
     
     <div class="sec">
     
      <i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i>
     
     </div>
     
     <div class="sec">
     
      <h3 class="address-title">ADDRESS</h3>
      
      <p class="address-1">8, Belgium, Brussels,</p>
      
      <p class="address-2">Liutte 207 New York, USA</p>
     
     </div>
     
    </div>
   
   </div>
   
  </div>
  
 </section>
```

[image: 100%]

[image: 25%]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting aspect ratio for page

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

I would also advise you to use flexbox for your layouts

[Flebox Guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: I don't want to use flexbox for now.

Comment: can you help me?

Comment: The problem i am facing is for desktop fluid layout, not for mobile version.

Comment: Try min-width also try experiment with font sizes, letter spacing and @media query. One of these should fix your problem